# openCV better way to draw contours

Tags: python, opencv

I've detected the hand based on ROI histograms using the code provided on the openCV website, and this is the result I've obtained[image]

Based on this result, I want to draw the contour, but the resulting image it's not the one I need for my future processing.
[image]

What I need to do in order to have a smoother contour? Thanks!

Comment: so your question is not about how to draw a contour but how to detect a  contour? Imho the contours present in the image are drawn perfectly... What you want is some kind of "concave-hull" method. Maybe you can start with a "convex-hull"

Answer (score 1):

Your image has too many "holes". Try with some [morphology](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/opening_closing_hats/opening_closing_hats.html)

This is C++ code, but you can easily port to Python. You may need to tweak the parameters a little.

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat3b img = imread("path_to_image");
    Mat1b binary;
    cvtColor(img, binary, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    threshold(binary, binary, 1, 255, THRESH_BINARY);

    Mat1b morph;
    Mat kernel = getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(11,11));
    morphologyEx(binary, morph, MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, Point(-1,-1), 3);

    vector<vector<Point>> contours;
    findContours(morph.clone(), contours, CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    /// Draw contours
    Mat3b draw = img.clone();
    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {
        drawContours(draw, contours, i, Scalar(0,0,255), 2);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If you *close* your image, you got better results, like this:

[image]

Probably you need, however, to get a better result from your former processing.